# Find probability density function

Tags: probability, statistics

i have a problem with following task:
$X_1,...,X_n$ are independent random variables with normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with expected value $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, 
$$Z=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(X_k-\mu)^2$$ And my task is to find it's denisity. After a while I've managed to transform it and see it's Chi-squared distribution. Thanks to wikipedia now I know denisity, but I guess I should make it from scratch maybe using variance or expected value? I would be more than glad for help.

Comment: this question on crossvalidated may be of help: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/proving-that-the-squares-of-normal-rvs-is-chi-square-distributed

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_related_to_chi-squared_distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y_k = \dfrac{X_k-\mu}{\sigma}$

Then $Y_1,\ldots , Y_n$ are independent random variables with normal distributions $N(0,1)$ i.e. expected value $0$ and variance $1$, and
$$Z=\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_k^2$$
which meets the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Definition) of a $\chi^2$-distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom

Comment: Yes, I come up with that. Knowing that this is $\chi^2$ -distribution, I can find denisity somewhere in internet. But I suspect it's expected from me to calculate it, which I am unsure how to.

Comment: Wikipedia gives a derivation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_related_to_chi-squared_distribution#Derivation_of_the_pdf_for_k_degrees_of_freedom though it is not trivial